# PHP update not recognized in Apache on FreeBSD

Tags: php, apache-2.4, freebsd, update, freebsd-ports

I'm trying to update the PHP installation on my FreeBSD machine.  I ran

```
portsnap fetch update
cd /usr/ports/lang/php56
make reinstall
cd /usr/ports/lang/php56-extensions
make reinstall
service apache24 restart
```

then reloaded the page where I have the output of `phpinfo()` displayed and it's still showing `5.6.24` but if I run `php --version` at a shell prompt, I get

```
PHP 5.6.31 (cli) (built: Aug 30 2017 13:40:53)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

Obviously I forgot a step here, but it's been a while since I did this and my memory is a bit foggy...

---

**EDIT**

As pointed out by [arrowd](https://serverfault.com/users/322531/arrowd), I had two more steps to run:

```
cd ../../www/mod_php56/
make clean reinstall
```

(Note that without the `make clean` the `5.6.24` working directories stuck around, I'm not sure why.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, reinstall `www/mod_php56` too.